# how to use open_ptrack instead of people detection program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I knew that some people have an interest in people detection while reading some articles on this site. So, I found open_ptrack on the web(http://openptrack.org/). So, Has someone experienced of using the package ? This package is available for Hydro and Ubuntu 13.04. My computer has hydro and Ubuntu 12.04. Could you tell me your experience if you have already used the package. For example, how to use the open_ptrack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149741/how-to-use-open_ptrack-instead-of-people-detection-program/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed open_ptrack as I follow the installation guide. I edited ros_configure.sh and calibration_toolkit_install.sh to match my PC environment.

ros_configure.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
#mkdir -p ~/workspace/ros/catkin/src
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make --force-cmake
#mkdir -p ~/workspace/ros/rosbuild
#rosws init ~/workspace/ros/rosbuild ~/workspace/ros/catkin/devel
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export KINECT_DRIVER=\"openni\"" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

# Update libfreenect driver for Kinect:
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/open_ptrack/scripts
chmod +x libfreenect_update.sh
./libfreenect_update.sh

# Install SwissRanger driver:
chmod +x mesa_install.sh
./mesa_install.sh
```

calibration_toolkit_install.sh

```
# Installer for 'calibration_toolkit' from GitHub (needed for multicamera calibration)
chmod +x ceres_install.sh
./ceres_install.sh
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/iaslab-unipd/calibration_toolkit 
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make --pkg calibration_msgs
catkin_make --force-cmake
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
You should avoid installing the package, because I can't confirm if the package works.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-09**:
Today, while my installing the package on Hydro and Ubuntu 13.04, I came across a compiling error.  As developing the package, it seems to have some bugs. I look forward to it, but I should wait a little longer. By the way, I use a ubuntu 12.04 , ubuntu 13.04 and Windows7 with parallels on Mac.